How to make statsmodels' ANOVA result match R's ANOVA result
The following question is sort of a concrete adaptation of a post on StatsExchange.
The following R script runs just fine:
library(reshape)

J1 <- c(9,6,8,7,10,6)
J2 <- c(2,1,4,1,5,2)
J3 <- c(5,3,6,2,6,4)
J4 <- c(8,2,8,6,9,7)
Subject <- c('S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6')
sf <- data.frame(Subject, J1, J2, J3, J4)
sf.df <- melt(sf, varnames=c("Subject", "Rater"))
anova(lm(value ~ Subject, sf.df))
anova(lm(value ~ Subject*variable, sf.df))

However, when I try to translate this into Python, I run into an exception that gets thrown from scipy.
Here's the equivalent Python script:
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

# Create the data
J1 = [9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 6]
J2 = [2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2]
J3 = [5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4]
J4 = [8, 2, 8, 6, 9, 7]
Subject = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6']

# Create the DataFrame
sf = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': Subject, 'J1': J1, 'J2': J2, 'J3': J3, 'J4': J4})
print(sf)

# Melt the DataFrame
sf_melted = pd.melt(sf, id_vars=['Subject'], var_name='Rater', value_name='Value')
print(sf_melted)

# Perform ANOVA
model1 = ols('Value ~ Subject', data=sf_melted).fit()
anova_table1 = sm.stats.anova_lm(model1, typ=2)
print(anova_table1)

model2 = ols('Value ~ Subject * Rater', data=sf_melted).fit()
anova_table2 = sm.stats.anova_lm(model2, typ=2)
print(anova_table2)

The ANOVA calculation for the first model runs just fine, but there seems to be an issue with the second model.
Here's the full stack trace:
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1717: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return np.dot(wresid, wresid) / self.df_resid

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[246], line 26
     23 print(anova_table1)
     25 model2 = ols('Value ~ Subject * Rater', data=sf_melted).fit()
---> 26 anova_table2 = sm.stats.anova_lm(model2, typ=2)
     27 print(anova_table2)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/anova.py:353, in anova_lm(*args, **kwargs)
    351 if len(args) == 1:
    352     model = args[0]
--> 353     return anova_single(model, **kwargs)
    355 if typ not in [1, "I"]:
    356     raise ValueError("Multiple models only supported for type I. "
    357                      "Got type %s" % str(typ))

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/anova.py:84, in anova_single(model, **kwargs)
     81     return anova1_lm_single(model, endog, exog, nobs, design_info, table,
     82                             n_rows, test, pr_test, robust)
     83 elif typ in [2, "II"]:
---> 84     return anova2_lm_single(model, design_info, n_rows, test, pr_test,
     85                             robust)
     86 elif typ in [3, "III"]:
     87     return anova3_lm_single(model, design_info, n_rows, test, pr_test,
     88                             robust)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/anova.py:207, in anova2_lm_single(model, design_info, n_rows, test, pr_test, robust)
    205 LVL = np.dot(np.dot(L1,robust_cov),L2.T)
    206 from scipy import linalg
--> 207 orth_compl,_ = linalg.qr(LVL)
    208 r = L1.shape[0] - L2.shape[0]
    209 # L1|2
    210 # use the non-unique orthogonal completion since L12 is rank r

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_decomp_qr.py:129, in qr(a, overwrite_a, lwork, mode, pivoting, check_finite)
    125     raise ValueError("Mode argument should be one of ['full', 'r',"
    126                      "'economic', 'raw']")
    128 if check_finite:
--> 129     a1 = numpy.asarray_chkfinite(a)
    130 else:
    131     a1 = numpy.asarray(a)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:603, in asarray_chkfinite(a, dtype, order)
    601 a = asarray(a, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    602 if a.dtype.char in typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(a).all():
--> 603     raise ValueError(
    604         "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
    605 return a

ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Things I've tried:

Changing library versions. I was originally on numpy 1.22.4 and scipy 1.12, and now I'm on numpy 2.0.0 and scipy 1.13.1.
I've tried enforcing categorical variables in the linear model by writing Value ~ Subject * C(Rater) for the second model. I wonder if it's not treating the data as categorical....but from what I've read statsmodels is supposed to correctly infer that any string variable is categorical, so this may be the wrong idea.

Can any R/Python/statsmodels experts help me resolve this?
The expected output (from the R script) is the following:
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Subject    5  56.208 11.2417  1.7947 0.1648
Residuals 18 112.750  6.2639               
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Subject           5 56.208  11.242               
Rater             3 97.458  32.486               
Subject:Rater    15 15.292   1.019               
Residuals         0  0.000               

^ Note that this expected output also corresponds with the output shown in the referenced StatsExchange post (the MeanSq value for the "Rater" variable of 32.486 is roughly the value of 32.49 associated with the "Judge" variable in the StatsExchange post).

Your Rater maybe should be converted to integers?
I'm not sure what's your expected output.
Try:
sf_melted['Rater'] = sf_melted['Rater'].str.slice(1).astype(int)
model2 = ols('Value ~ Subject * Rater', data=sf_melted).fit()
anova_table2 = sm.stats.anova_lm(model2, typ=2, missing=0)
print(anova_table2)

Output:
                   sum_sq    df         F    PR(>F)
Subject         56.208333   5.0  1.273843  0.336760
Rater            0.408333   1.0  0.046270  0.833298
Subject:Rater    6.441667   5.0  0.145987  0.977485
Residual       105.900000  12.0       NaN       NaN


I edited the original post to show the expected output. Your result doesn't quite match the expected output.

anova() in R produces a Type I ANOVA table (see e.g. here), so to get the same output, you must pass typ=1 to anova_lm. You can verify that when you do that, statsmodels' outputs are the same as R's below.1
For the first model:
sm.stats.anova_lm(model1, typ=1)

            df      sum_sq    mean_sq         F    PR(>F)
Subject    5.0   56.208333  11.241667  1.794678  0.164769
Residual  18.0  112.750000   6.263889       NaN       NaN

For the second model:
sm.stats.anova_lm(model2, typ=1)

                 df        sum_sq    mean_sq    F  PR(>F)
Subject         5.0  5.620833e+01  11.241667  0.0     NaN
Rater           3.0  9.745833e+01  32.486111  0.0     NaN
Subject:Rater  15.0  1.529167e+01   1.019444  0.0     NaN
Residual        0.0  1.778203e-25        inf  NaN     NaN

On a side note, if we try to produce a Type 2 ANOVA table in R for model2, we also get an error:
> car::Anova(lm(value ~ Subject*variable, sf.df), type=2)
Error in Anova.lm(lm(value ~ Subject * variable, sf.df), type = 2) : 
  residual df = 0

1 For model2, mean_sq is inf for statsmodels' anova_lm() but NaN for R's anova(). This is due to the rounding errors in sum_sq in the two functions. For R's anova() the sum_sq of Residual is 0 while it is 1.778203e-25 for statsmodels' anova_lm().
